# Forward linux logs to fluentd on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, rsyslog, fluentd

On one VM I have this in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

```
*.* @192.168.29.1:42185

#  Default rules for rsyslog.
```

On the vm with fluentd I have this:

I have this in `/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf`

```
<source>
  type syslog
  port 42185
  tag  rsyslog
</source>

<match rsyslog.**>
  type copy
  <store>
    # for debug (see /var/log/td-agent.log)
    type stdout
  </store>
  <store>
    type elasticsearch
    logstash_format true
    flush_interval 10s # for testing.
  </store>
</match>
```

But nothing seems to be getting sent to the remote machine, as I look in /var/log/td-agent.log and I see

```
2014-08-08 10:51:10 -0700 [info]: adding source type="syslog"
2014-08-08 10:51:10 -0700 [info]: adding source type="forward"
2014-08-08 10:51:10 -0700 [info]: adding source type="http"
2014-08-08 10:51:10 -0700 [info]: adding source type="debug_agent"
2014-08-08 10:51:10 -0700 [info]: adding match pattern="td.*.*" type="tdlog"
2014-08-08 10:51:10 -0700 [info]: adding match pattern="debug.**" type="stdout"
2014-08-08 10:51:10 -0700 [info]: adding match pattern="rsyslog.**" type="copy"
2014-08-08 10:51:10 -0700 [info]: listening fluent socket on 0.0.0.0:24224
2014-08-08 10:51:10 -0700 [info]: listening dRuby uri="druby://127.0.0.1:24230" object="Engine"
2
```

I don't know why the logs aren't being sent, and I don't see how to tell if there is something going wrong with `rsyslog` and it just isn't sending the files.

Comment: Have you tried using tcpdump to see whether the traffic is being received on the remote machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, rsyslog forwards logs over TCP (in the config file, this is listed as "for reliability"), but fluentD's listener defaults to listening on UDP. This change to your fluentD config should allow you to receive the logs on TCP:

```
<source>
  type syslog
  port 42185
  protocol_type tcp
  tag  rsyslog
</source>
```

I would check with TCP dump whether the traffic is being received on the agent, if you're still not receiving logs after making this change:

```
tcpdump -i any port 42185
```

This should also indicate whether TCP or UDP is being received (only specifying `port`, and not `tcp` or `udp` as well)

EDIT: in addition to this, make sure your rsyslog config is correct: all examples I've seen and used, have a double `@@` in the forward rule:

```
*.* @@192.168.29.1:42185
```

http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_reliable_forwarding.html

Comment: Thank you, I got it working. I forgot that tcpdump will also consume the packets, so I wasted some time on that.  I think the protocol_type was the final piece missing.